# Windows batch outputs a line feed female character

Tags: bash

An extra form feed character is printed out in all bash scripts in the form of a "female symbol".

- Character: ♀
- Numerical code: **&#9792;**
- Hex code: **&#x2640;**

The main issue is that form feeds ar not printable characters. As such, most bash scripts that proccess paths have no filtering mechanisms implemented for form feeds and crash.

I am trying to build an APK for android using the Ant tool and the female symbol breaks the scripts.

I can also see the female symbol in all PHP scripts run from bash. Below is a simple test script:

```
 if (isset($argv[1])) {
     echo "\nString\n";
 } else {
     passthru('php -f ' . __FILE__ . ' arg1');
 }
```

When I run this line `php -f script.php` (where the **script.php** contains the code above) the output is the following:

```
♀
String
```

So once again, this is not a program-specific issue, it is system-wide. And I have failed to reproduce it on another machine.

I have been searching for an answer to what might cause this for about a week with no success.

Do you know what might be the root cause of this?

Comment: No woman no cry. But this is a serious issue. I really need to figure this one out.

Comment: What operating system?  If Windows, which might be the case given the title, then which versions of bash and php are you using?  (e.g. Cygwin, PHP on Windows, etc.)

Comment: @DonCruickshank I am using Windows 7; the PHP version is irrelevant since this issue also occurs when trying to build an APK using Ant (Java, latest versions for both the JDK and JRE) but since you asked it's PHP v5.3.5

Answer (score 8):

I've got similar problem today with form feed symbol:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=!" %a in ('echo test') do (set RELAY=%a)

C:\>echo %RELAY%
♀test
```

The problem was CLS command in the AutoRun of cmd.
startup.bat:

```
@echo off
doskey ps=C:\tools\tasklist_by_name.bat $1
doskey kill=C:\tools\taskkill_by_pid.bat $1
doskey list=doskey /macros$bsort
cls
```

It runs with this

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
AutoRun "C:\tools\startup.bat"
```

When I remove CLS command it's OK.
You can check it on your system, maybe AutoRun is set on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal batch script to detect the problem:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('echo a') do if not "a"=="%%a" (
  echo error : found problem in AutoRun cmd (you can try to remove cls and virtual terminal sequences)
  exit /B 1
)
rem etc.
exit /B 0
```