# Iterating over files in directory prepends extra character to filename

Tags: batch-file

For some strange reason this batch script is prepending an extra character to the filename while iterating over the non-hidden files in a directory.

See this example:

[image: Prepended character example]

Plain-text:

```
FOR /F %i in ('dir "*.sql" /A-H /b') DO @echo %i
```

Output:

```
♀test.sql
```

This is an issue because when I try to open %i it says it doesn't exist.

I could replace the first character, but this script needs to work on multiple machines and not just mine. This only happens on my machine. Any idea how to fix it?

**Update**

[image: Hex Editor]

So 0x0C (form feed?) seems to be the character inserted.

Comment: Maybe there is an `echo` alternative (.bat, .cmd, .exe) that is being invoked instead of the internal command. Can you try with `@echo(%i`?

Comment: @MCND In the actual batch script it's passing `%%i` into [osql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213090(v=sql.80).aspx). That's then throwing an error because `♀test.sql` doesn't exist, but `test.sql` does; however, I just tried with `@echo(%i` and that also outputs `♀test.sql`. It's very strange.

Comment: wild guess but what is your code page? What is the output of `CHCP` command?

Comment: @npocmaka `437` which is the same on the other machines too. I just tried a couple different code pages (`65001`, `866`) and it still persists.

Comment: @dhsto - what if you use `%%~nxi`

Comment: @npocmaka I tried `FOR /F %i in ('dir "*.sql" /A-H /b') DO @echo %~nxi` in command prompt and it's still outputting `♀test.sql`.

Comment: Might that be a problem with the filename, not with the command? What does it say, when you try it with a file created with `echo blah >test.txt` ?

Comment: @Stephan no, regardless of the filename it doesn't work. It always prepends that character while iterating.

Comment: Try it in codepage 850 as a test.  If it still fails then use `dir *.sql /b >file.txt` and examine the file with a hex viewer to see if there are any odd characters in it.

Comment: @foxidrive good idea! It seems like `0x0C` is the character prepended, but only when iterating. See my updated question above.

Comment: Do you have a file called `echo` anyplace in the current directory or on the PATH that has a formfeed in it?  Maybe `echo.bat` with `@echo ffchar%*` or just a file called plain echo ?

Comment: @foxidrive no, I changed the PATH to be an empty folder and it still didn't work. Plus, when I pass the value of `%i` into `osql` it will also complain the file doesn't exist because of the form-feed in the filename.

Comment: Now that the thread was reopened - it would seem likely that you were pasting the same command line every time you tried it (and an embedded character was in the command).  Re-typing the line should have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, take a look on answer on Stack Overflow question [Windows batch outputs a line feed female character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504408/).

Second, take a look on Microsoft's TechNet article [Command Processor\AutoRun](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779439.aspx), or read in help output after entering `cmd /?` about **AutoRun** registry value.

It looks like on the computer on which a form-feed is written first to file on redirecting output of command `dir`, there is a batch file or another command configured to be automatically executed on start of command line processor. And one of those commands is responsible for the form-feed character.

This can be checked quickly without first looking into Windows registry by starting `cmd.exe` with option `/D` and then enter the commands as it can be seen on screenshot in question. If the file `file.txt` is now without a form-feed as first character, there could be indeed an autorun command responsible for this unwanted behavior.

Start now `regedit.exe` and check the value **AutoRun** under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

and

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

On my computer the value **AutoRun** does not exist at all in HKCU and is empty in HKLM.

Also run in a command prompt window on this computer just `set` and look on the environment variables

- **ComSpec** ... should be `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`
- **PATHEXT** ... should be `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH`
- **PATH** ... should start with `C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;`

It could be that the command processor on this computer is not `cmd.exe` or **PATH** starts with a different folder than System32 directory in Windows directory and this folder contains also a `cmd.exe` or other console applications which can be found in System32 directory of Windows.

Those 3 very important environment variables can be configured in **Control Panel - System - Advanced - Environment Variables**  according to [Environment Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653.aspx) documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much! The `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` was the issue. I forgot that a very long time ago I had set that to run a cmd file that would alias `ls` with `dir`.