# My bat file can't run correctly, why?

Tags: batch-file, operating-system

Create a new file test.bat, the content is as follows:

> echo aa;

and execute it in the dos command line,

> test.bat

there are no output in the window. But when I tested it in another computer, it outputs

> aa

When I double click the bat file, it always disappeared suddenly even I add a "pause" clause line in the test.bat file. Both the systems are Window XP. Can sb tell me where is the problem, please?

I have checked all the things Mofi suggested, but the problem remains.

Now, I divscover when reboot to the system using another Administrator account. All is fine.

So, whether the problem comes from the registry record of the Windows XP?

Comment: You called the batch file `echo.bat` is my guess.  Try calling it `echoed.bat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer on [Iterating over files in directory prepends extra character to filename](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25712811/3074564) where I have already explained what to check if batch files are not working as expected.

The environment variables **ComSpec**, **PATHEXT** and **PATH** should be verified by you first. And check also the values of registry key **Command Processor** as explained in referenced answer. Also **Autorun** value of key `Command Processor` is very critical.

Further, start **Regedit** and check standard value of registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat` displayed on right side. It should be `batfile`. Then go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile`, open it and navigate to subkey `open` - `command`. The standard value is `"%1" %*`. It could be that your Windows registry is partly corrupt which makes it not possible to run a batch file by double click.

A check for a problem with registry would be opening a command prompt window by running

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

via **Run** entry in start menu of Windows. Then run your batch file from within the command prompt window.

You should also run from a command prompt window

```
C:\Windows\System32\chkdsk.exe C: /F
```

and confirm running the check disk tool of Windows on next boot of Windows. Then restart Windows to let this tool check the file system for errors resulting in 1 or more corrupt files. If an error was really detected in file system, run after Windows finished starting from a command prompt window

```
C:\Windows\System32\chkdsk.exe C: /F /R
```

Confirm running this tool once again on next boot of Windows, but this time with read/write tests on all sectors of your hard disk and repairing sectors if that is possible at all. It can take several hours depending on size of drive C: to finish this task.

---

**Added on 2014-09-28:**

### Anti-virus application

Do you have checked already the configuration of the anti-virus application?

It could be that it blocks the execution of all *.bat files.

### Windows System Restore

Do you have already tried to use Windows System Restore for the account on which batch file execution fails and go back to a restore point of a date on which you are sure that batch file execution worked?

If `ntuser.dat` or `ntuser.dat.log` (= registry of current user) is partly corrupt or something is misconfigured in Windows registry for this user account, this would be the easiest method to get back a working environment for the account.

### Process Monitor Analysis

As execution of batch files does not work only with one account, the reason must be a corrupt or wrong set key or value in registry of this account.

I suggest to download and run free tool [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from Sysinternals (Microsoft) using first the account on which batch file execution does not work as expected.

The first displayed on start of this tool is a dialog to configure a filter. Select from first list **Process Name**, let **is** selected on second list, enter **cmd.exe** in edit field, and let **Include** selected in last list. Click next on button **Include** and then on **OK**.

Now in main application window of Process Monitor click on last 3 symbols in toolbar to toggle off those features resulting in monitoring only registry and file system accesses. Clear current list by clicking on fifth symbol in toolbar or by pressing Ctrl+X.

Now double click on your sample batch file in Windows Explorer. Then switch batck to Process Monitor, scroll up to beginning and look line by line what happens on executing of a batch file. Perhaps you can see something which you think is not correct.

The column **Result** should show only *SUCCESS* and *NAME NOT FOUND* and rarely *NO MORE ENTRIES* for registry entries in log. *INVALID* in column **Result** is not good. The log can be saved as CSV file with Ctrl+S or by clicking on disk symbol in toolbar.

Exit Process Monitor, logout from this account, logon on other account, start here also Process Monitor, configure the same filter, execute same batch file and save also this log into a CSV file. Compare the 2 CSV files and look for differences (other than time and line number).

### Windows Registry Compare

Another method to find out what is different between the 2 accounts resulting in batch file execution not working is comparing the registry hives of those 2 accounts. In both accounts start **Regedit** and export entire key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` to a *.reg file. Compare the two registry exports with a text comparison tool. The new administrator account has definitely less keys and values. Interesting are those blocks with just similar, but not identical lines.

Most interesting are the keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.bat
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\batfile
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

Some keys from this list can be missing completely. That would be okay as in this case the same key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE is taken into account by Windows. But when a key is missing in account on which batch file execution fails, it should be also missing in the other account, or something is wrong here.

What could be a big and hard to find problem is a registry key which is displayed on viewing the registry tree with **Regedit**, but when clicking on the key it cannot be read.

I have seen such partly corrupt registry keys already several times and it is very hard to fix such a registry error. This happens for example if an application removes a registry key without removing it also from index table of the registry.

Totally unexpected things happen if a registry key is present in index, but does not exist anymore in registry. For example I fixed once an issue where `HKLM\Software\Classes\mailto` was in index list, but did not exist anymore in registry. When the user clicked on a mailto link, Windows started creating new emails in Outlook in a loop until Windows run out of resources and user restarted Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Please add @ before echo, like this:

```
@echo aa
@pause
```

Its working in my Windows7 machine.

Comment: I think the usage of @ is not output the output of the command following it. I just tested it, it can't works.