# My first android program build fails. Error: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: android, android-studio

The error messages copied from android studio are as follows:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: 
Failed to run command:

E:\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\dx.bat --dex --num-threads=4 
--output F:\AndroidStudioProjects\GeoQuiz\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug    
F:\AndroidStudioProjects\GeoQuiz\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug  
F:\AndroidStudioProjects\GeoQuiz\app\build\intermediates\dependency-cache\debug

Error Code:
    1
Output:
    The system cannot find the path specified.


Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I previously used the eclipse IDE, appeared the same error message, which is "The system cannot find the path specified".

And I searched nearly all the similar question from the web, the problem not solved yet.

The IDE internally use some .bat file to find the java.exe location, but my .bat file not function for some reason unknown.

So I suspect the problem comes from my another problem: 
[My bat file can't run correctly, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072181/my-bat-file-cant-run-correctly-why)